# MongoMapper Custom Types don't work

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

I've been using MongoMapper for a couple weeks now and like a lot of its features. One of the most appealing ones is the ability to define custom key types and validation methods (see "Custom Types" on this page: http://mongomapper.com/documentation/types.html).

However, I tried using them with a small test and the validation methods aren't firing in my case. Here's the code:

```
require 'mongo_mapper'

MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new('localhost', 27017)
MongoMapper.database = "mmtestdb"

class ACustomType
    def self.to_mongo(value)
        puts "to_mongo is being called"
        "A Safe Value"
    end
    def self.from_mongo(value)
        puts "from_mongo is being called"
        "A Safer Value"
    end
end

class TestClass
    include MongoMapper::Document

    key :my_name, type: ACustomType
end

TestClass.delete_all
new_object = TestClass.new
new_object.my_name = "Unsafe Value!"
puts new_object.inspect
new_object.save
puts TestClass.all.inspect
```

And here are my results:

```
#<TestClass _id: BSON::ObjectId('525db435ab48651f64000001'), my_name: "Unsafe Value!">
[DEPRECATED] The 'safe' write concern option has been deprecated in favor of 'w'.
[#<TestClass _id: BSON::ObjectId('525db435ab48651f64000001'), my_name: "Unsafe Value!">]
```

I'm aware of the "write concern" issue and patched it using the solution at https://github.com/mongomapper/mongomapper/issues/507. Here's that code:

```
# Monkey Patch to solve issue https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/issues/507
module MongoMapper
  module Plugins
    module Querying
      private
        def save_to_collection(options={})
          @_new = false
          collection.save(to_mongo, :w => options[:safe] ? 1 : 0)
        end
    end
  end
end
```

I omitted it from my test example because the results are the same with or without it.

Can anyone help? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to define the key as:

```
 key :my_name, ACustomType
```

Rather than:

```
 key :my_name, type: ACustomType
```

`key`'s method signature is `def key(name, type, options = {})`

Comment: Right under my nose the whole time. I came over to MongoMapper from Mongoid and didn't internalize the syntax differences. Thanks so much for your help @chris-heald.